# Periodically Deleting Rows in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have an audit table setup which essentially mirrors one of my tables along with a date, user and command type. Here's how it might look like:

```
AuditID      UserID Individual    modtype   user  audit_performed
1           1239      Day Meff      INSERT    dbo   2010-11-04 14:50:56.357
2           2334      Dasdf fdlla   INSERT    dbo   2010-11-04 14:51:07.980
3           3324      Dasdf fdla    DELETE    dbo   2010-11-04 14:51:11.130
4           5009      Day Meffasdf  UPDATE    dbo   2010-11-04 14:51:12.777
```

Since these types of tables can get big pretty quick - I was thinking of putting in some sort of automatic delete of the older rows. So for example if I have 3 months of history - if I could delete the first month while retaining the last two. And again all of this must be automatic - I imagine once a certain date is hit, a query activates and deletes the oldest month with audit data. What is the best way to do this?

I'm using SQL Server 2005 by the way.

Comment: I would avoid creating a trigger on the Audit to delete old entries.  This will only hand you a first class ticket in to a world of pain - especially if you are creating the audit entry using a trigger in the first place.  Best option would be to schedule a daily SQL Agent Job at a time where there will no or little activity on the Audit table. Oh and at a time that doesn't interfere with your Backup and Maintenance Plans.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [SQL Server agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx)..you can schedule a repeating job like deleting entries from the current audit table after certain period. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186273.aspx) is how you would do it.

I would recommend storing the data in another table  audit_archive table  and deleting it from the current audit table. So, that in case you want some history you still have it and your table also doesn't get too big.

Answer (score 5):

A SQL agent job should be fine here.  You definitely don't need to do this on every single insert with a trigger.  I doubt you even need to do it every day.  You could schedule a job that runs once a month and clears out anything older than 2 months (so at most you'd have 3 months of data minus 1 day at any given time).

Answer (score 3):

You could try a trigger every time a row is added it will clear anything older than 3 months.

You could also try SQL Agent to run a script every day that will do that.

Comment: +1 for a SQL Agent job.  I would absolutely stay away from a trigger for this (but I won't give -1 for that :).

Comment: Indeed, the trigger would probably fire off far too often. Another option would be to use an external program to run the query. Maybe fired off from Windows Task Scheduler. All depends on your access rights to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using triggers?  You could define a trigger to run when you add a row (on INSERT) that deletes any rows that are more than three months old.

Comment: You would/could be adding a LOT of overhead to every insert if you were to do this with triggers.

Comment: Dangerous idea. Triggers are very nasty to debug and can wreak havoc if not guarded.